# The valuation of finite extension of an non-archimedean field

Tags: nt.number-theory, non-archimedean-fields

Let $(k,|.|)$ be a non-archimedean complete field and $(L,|.|)$ be a finite extension of $(k,|.|)$, $[L:k]=n$, such that  $L=k(\xi)$. Let $\phi$ the homomorphism of $k$-Banach algebra
$$\begin{array}{rcl}
\phi: (L,|.|)&\to &(k^n,||.||)\\
f_1+f_2\xi+\cdots+f_n\xi^{n-1}&\mapsto &(f_1,f_2,\cdots,f_n)\\
\end{array}$$
where $||.||$ is the maximum norm.
Since we know that, all $k$-norms over a finite $k$-vector space are equivalent, the operator $\phi$ must be bounded. 
Is there any reference for the computation of the operator norm of $\phi$? Or less precise, 
an explicit $c$ such that
$$\max |f_i|\leq  C|f_1+f_2\xi+\cdots+f_n\xi^{n-1}|.$$